# cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, node.js, express

I have been making a small website for studying. but I met an error like title. For an answer, I search the internet all over.. I can't find the answer.

My system is Ubuntu, node.js, express and mysql.

app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'Company'
});

var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080');
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  fs.readFile('list.html', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM prodects', function (error, results) {
       response.send(ejs.render(data, {
        data: results
      }));
    });
  });
});
```

list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>List Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>List Page</h1>
  <a href="/insert">INSERT DATA</a>
  <hr />
  <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>DELETE</th>
      <th>EDIT</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>Model Number</th>
      <th>Series</th>
    </tr>
    <% data.forEach(function(item, index) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/delete/<%= item.id %>">Delete</a></td>

    </tr>
    <% }); %>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

There is an eorror at 20 line; 
On my screen, It shows "cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined".

Comment: Well.... you don't need to read the `list.html` file using `fs`. You should do... `ejs.render( 'list.html', { data: results } )`

Comment: Also... `data` can probably be `null`... as I think you wanted `products` instead of `prodects` in your query... hence there is an error in executing the query and the result is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you get an error in the callback to `client.query` and therefore `results` is null.

Perhaps the error is a misspelled table name? prodects -> products?

Comment: Cool :) Btw, when someone answers a question on Stack Overflow it's nice if you tag that answer as accepted, so that the question is not lingering as "unanswered"